# Как собрать проект в APK файл?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, apk

Заранее хотел бы отметить, что не имею никакого опыта в этой теме, поэтому многие используемые мной термины могут быть использованы неправильно, а вопросы быть глупыми. Есть следующая задача, "собрать" готовый проект в Android Studio, весь код уже написан, есть файл build.gradle и так далее, задача лишь взять эти файлы и сделать из них APK файл для последующего запуска на телефоне, поиск не дал нужных результатов, ибо все найденное в интернете,  было о написании с нуля. Извините еще раз, если задаю глупый или некорректный вопрос, заранее спасибо!

Comment: В android studio нажмите на значок молотка и должен собраться с debug-подписью.
PS: Если вы нашли статьи о том как написать android-приложение, то там обычно в конце приводят описание этапа запуска. Статей и видео в интернете на эту тему куча. Если вы не смогли этой найти, то плохо искали.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Answer (score 2):

Для создания отчуждаемого файла вам нужно сгенерировать APK. Для этого нажимаем на "Build":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираем "Generate Signed Bundle/APK":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В открывшемся окошке выбираем APK:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заполняем все необходимые поля:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь будет нужен сертификат для подписи, если у вас его нет, то при нажатии на кнопку "Create New" создаем новый для себя (дальше просто его нужно будет выбирать, генерировать новый не нужно будет):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираем вариант сборки и отмечаем две галки внизу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нажимаем Finish, и у вас начнется сборка. По завершению внизу появится уведомление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при нажатии на "Locate" вы перейдете в директорию где будет сгенерированный APK файл.